# View Django query in SQL

Tags: python, django

I have the following django query:

```
entries = Catalog.objects.exclude(
                              itunes_pulldown_error_status = ITUNES_PULLDOWN_APPLE_INTERNAL_ERROR, date_last_updated_affiliate__lte = now-datetime.timedelta(hours=48)
                         ).exclude(
                            itunes_pulldown_error_status = ITUNES_PULLDOWN_NO_CONTENT_FOUND, date_last_updated_affiliate__lte = now-datetime.timedelta(days=7)
                         ).filter(
                              provider__premiere_can_view_provider=True, platform_id='ITUNES'
                        ).filter(
                              Q(date_last_updated_transporter__isnull=True)
                             |Q(date_last_updated_affiliate__gte=F('date_last_updated_transporter'))
                        ).extra(
                            where=['apple_id mod %s=%s' % (divisor, remainder)]
                        ).distinct()[:1000]
```

How would I view the SQL that this query produces in the python shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view the SQL that is produced by doing:

```
>>> entries = Catalog.objets.exclude(...)
>>> print entries.query
```

Comment: You can also list all SQL queries executed on a particular page using [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar).